# Higher Order Polynomial Interpolation

Tags: computer-science, approximation-theory

I am trying to approximate some log and exp functions in my code. I have implemented linear and cubic splines, but I want more accuracy. I am thinking about biquadratic splines (4th order, quartic), but am not able to understand it. Can someone please help me out with biquadratic splines. Something simple to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

To get better accuracy, you need to use a curve that has more degrees of freedom. The whole point of splines is that you get more degrees of freedom by adding more segments, not by increasing degree.

If you really want to increase degree, instead, then you may as well use a polynomial to do the approximation. High accuracy polynomial approximations are easy to construct. The best tool for doing this is [chebfun](http://www.chebfun.org/)